# Move rows to Specific Rows on another sheet based on True or False Check Box- Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I appreciate you taking the time to review my question. Hopefully, there is a simple way to do this. **Intention:** One form's output to share information between employees who handle different "levels" separated into different sheets. Once they handle their portion, they check a box and the info goes to the next sheet for the next employee to handle so on and so forth until the job is done.

The data from the form is imported to the first sheet called "Upcoming". Once checkbox in "A" is checked, it moves to the "Current" sheet. This part of the script works however, it is placing the information on the first row without information in it. I have checkboxes in the "Current" sheet in columns "A" and "B". I need it to place column "C:S" into the "Current" sheet's column "C:S" starting with the first row. How can I make it ignore what's in column A and B and place it on the same line starting with "C"? My plan is to duplicate this code, formula, query or even macro to each sheet with check boxes the whole way through. The below image shows where it is placing it in the target sheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxJWq.png)

I've tried everything I can think of. Hoping there is a simpler way to go about this than I am thinking of. Maybe just a conditional formatting and macro? I'm at a loss.

Here is the Code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Upcoming
  // target sheet of move to named Current
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Upcoming" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,3,1,25);
    s.getRange(row, 3, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Here is the google sheet and form:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AzDYI2OG0uGXNXIDN0nsOvEf7TItn4elrYZdroWDAGQ/edit?usp=sharing

Any guidance to the right information is appreciated. Thanks for reading this and for your time!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. From your question, I cannot understand about the current issue of your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them? 2. Unfortunately, I cannot open your sample Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Current Script State: Grabs row content based on Cell value in column "A" from sourceSheet "Upcoming". When marked "true" entire row goes to the targetSheet "Current" in the next available row. I want the row populate in Column C in or 2 or at the top of the sheet. I adjusted the permissions on the googlesheet. Sorry about that.

Comment: Goal: We have three people who handle three different jobs that require the same information, let's call it Mr. Jones. I want a checkbox that when each person is done with Mr. Jones, his info moves to the another sheet for the next person to do their part. Once they are done they will also check a box which will move Mr. Jones to the next sheet and so on until the entire process for Mr. Jones is complete.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect it. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood your question right, in which case you can use the below which will work to do this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var up = ss.getSheetByName('Upcoming');
  var cr = ss.getSheetByName('Current');
  var dr = cr.getDataRange();
  var lr = dr.getLastRow();
  var rng = e.range;
  if(rng.getSheet().getSheetName() === 'Upcoming' && e.value === 'TRUE') {
    var row = up.getRange(rng.getRow(),2,1,18).getValues();
    cr.getRange(lr,3,1,18).setValues(row)
    cr.getRange(lr,1).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just tried this. So far, it does the same thing as the code I have without deleting the content from the sourceSheet. I removed the +1 from the last line for: cr.getRange(lr,3,1,25).setValues(row) and that put the information on the right row! But then every subsequent one that I tried went to the bottom.

Comment: It looks like you have checkboxes in column A, the script would class this as data - you will need to remove all these then you can insert a checkbox by doing ```cr.getRange(lr,1).insertCheckboxes();``` within the if statement on the script (I've edited the answer to include this)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm definitely on the right track now. Thank you so much for your time!!